# A bag contains 10 red and 20 green marbles. Draw 5 without replacement. What is the probability of getting 2 red and 3 green?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I know how to get the probability of drawing marbles all of the same color, but I don't know how to code it to get 2 red and 3 green.

```
random.seed(42)

total = 0
trials = 10000

for _ in range(trials):
    
    draw = random.sample(range(1,31),5)
    
    if (max(draw) <= 20) or ((min(draw) > 20 and max(draw) < 30)):
        total += 1
        
total/trials
```

Comment: Forget code: how would you calculate this if you were doing it on paper?

Comment: You don't CODE it to get 2 red and 3 green.  You pull 5 marbles, and check what you GOT.

Answer (score 1):

For each trial (each time you draw 5 marbles) you need to keep count of how many are red and how many are green. If exactly 2 are red and 3 are green, increment your `total` counter.

```
import random

random.seed(42)

total = 0
trials = 10000

for _ in range(trials):

    red = 0
    green = 0

    draw = random.sample(range(1, 31), 5)
    for m in draw:
        if m <= 10:
            # we'll say marbles 1-10 are red, 11-30 are green
            red += 1
        else:
            green += 1

    if red == 2 and green == 3:
        total += 1

print(total / trials)
```

Comment: Better yet, just sample a list like `['r']*10 + ['g']*20`. Two `str` values are distinct marbles even if their "label" is the same. Then you just need to count the number of `r`s and `g`s in `draw`, something made trivial by `collections.counter`.